# Is it possible to re-route my incoming cellphone calls to Skype or to similar Internet call services?

Tags: skype, forwarding, mobile-phone

I have a local mobile cellphone line/number and I'm going to travel outside my country for 3 months. I want to know if is possible to re-route my incoming cellphone calls to my Skype (or any other similar services) in order to attend my calls outside my country without paying roaming fees.

Comment: What is your service provider and what country is it located?

Comment: For clarification purposes, my cellphone service provider is ICE and is located in Costa Rica, central america.

Comment: Could you please edit that info into the question so that others can see it easily?

Answer (score 2):

Call forwarding has been around for a while.  You can do it with many cell phones or have your phone company do it for you on a permanent basis.

Comment: This is too broad an answer and too broad a question. We expect answers to be specific and include details on how to solve the problem. Though I do admit that the question is too broad, as it does not specify the specific provider that the poster is using.

Comment: He can post a new question then.  I think stackoverflow has too many questions that should be left unrevised.  We should skip this "revise the question and get new answers" section.